# NextJS locale differs from configured defaultLocale

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, next.js

As the title says, I configured my `next.config.js` using the default Next JS 10 locale routing like so:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['nl-NL', 'en-GB'],
    defaultLocale: 'nl-NL',
    localeDetection: false,
  },
...
}
```

What I assume would happen that is that when I surf to `localhost:3000` my locale would be `nl-NL`.
However when I log `context` from `getStaticProps` in the console the result for `localhost:3000` is:

```
{
  locales: [ 'nl-NL', 'en-GB' ],
  locale: 'en-GB',
  defaultLocale: 'nl-NL'
}
```

for `localhost:3000/nl-NL` it does give me the right locale:

```
{
  locales: [ 'nl-NL', 'en-GB' ],
  locale: 'nl-NL',
  defaultLocale: 'nl-NL'
}
```

I would expect the `localhost:3000` would give me the default locale, especially since I turned of detection.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue with that same setup. Are you certain you're not overriding the locale somewhere, somehow?

Comment: Maybe, but I have no clue where. Does next.js save it somewhere else too?

Answer (score 0):

Noticed I was running Next 10.0.0, updated which solved my issue.